# Invalid SCA token in unix

Tags: shell, unix, private-key, sca, rs256

I am trying to generate a JWT and sign it with node private key. Private key is in txt format.

```
token_header=echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/ | sed -E s/=+$// 

token_body=echo -n '{"exp": '1706896597',"iat":'1706896701',"iss":"123456-us-xxx","jti":"'123456_xxx_123'","SystemInitiated":true}' | base64 | sed s/\+/-/ | sed -E s/=+$// 

token_signature=echo -n "$token_header.$token_body" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary -sign PrivateKey.key | openssl enc -base64 | tr -d '\n=' | tr -- '+/' '-_' 

complete_jwt_token=echo -n "$token_header.$token_body.$token_signature"
```

Using a curl command, to pass this "complete_jwt_token" and invoke an API request.

Result of curl:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid SCA","error_uri":"http://some-uri?code=401"}
```

Kindly advise.
Please let me know in which format private key should be.

curl command should post the request and receive a response.

Comment: Your posted script won't work at all without either backticks or `$( ... )` for process substitution; assuming you just added that mistake just to impede any assistance, your first two conversions to base64 need to translate both + to - AND / to _ and delete (trailing) = AND any nontrailing newline (unless you use `base64 -w0` instead), like your third does. It's easiest to use the same method for all of them; I prefer `tr`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy

Kindly advice.

Comment: @Darren Smith
Kindly advice.

Comment: Thank You @dave_thompson_085
Still curl cmd results  Invalid SCA(-w0 and tr). Any advice will be very helpful.

export issdt=`date +%s`;
export expdt=`expr $issdt + 1800`;

hdr=$(echo -n '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}' | base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '=');

body=$(echo -n '{"exp": "${expdt}","iat": "${issdt}","iss":"123593-xxxcm-pds","jti":"'123593_XXX_123'","SystemInitiated":true}' | base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '=');
  
sign=$(echo -n "$hdr.$body" | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac decrypted_PrivateKey.key.txt_1743byte -binary | base64 | tr '+/' '-_' | tr -d '=');
  
jwt="$jwt.$sign";

Comment: echo $sign is too short. 
3x0SdtM13gB2BhPQnIjlIwZon38cqIA01i6PdSUzlDc

Comment: Mohammed: Don't put code, except at most one very short line, in comments -- it's unreadable. Don't put important information about your question (including updates) in comments -- SX/SO is designed NOT to operate as a time-wasting chatroom, and comments are often deleted. (I'm pretty sure that as the only nonauthor commenter I get autonotified for edit, but if you want to make sure it's okay to comment with @ and something very brief like 'info added' or 'see edit'.)